# Help problem when updating libxatracker2_19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2_amd64.deb

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I can not update this package, it always gives the same error

```
:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Calculando la actualización... Hecho
El paquete indicado a continuación se instaló de forma automática y ya no es necesario.
  libllvm7
Utilice «sudo apt autoremove» para eliminarlo.
Se actualizarán los siguientes paquetes:
  gnome-shell gnome-shell-common libxatracker2
3 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 1.280 kB/2.131 kB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 329 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libxatracker2 amd64 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2
  Falló la conexión [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Fallo al obtener http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker2_19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2_amd64.deb  Falló la conexión [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos, ¿quizás deba ejecutar «apt-get update» o deba intentarlo de nuevo con --fix-missing?
```

Comment: A *very rough* [english translation](https://pastebin.com/sfu3TMhH)